# How to update tabBar badge value on receiving notification

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode8

How can I make a background API call on receiving notification to update tab bar badge value in swift 2.3?

I am using following code to update badge value on remote notification:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    pushDictionary = userInfo

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PushNotification", object: self, userInfo: userInfo)

    let pushNotification = PushNotification(dictionary: pushDictionary!)
    notification.subtitleText = pushNotification.message

    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {

        if pushNotification.type != nil {
            if pushNotification.type == "vc1"{
                self.tabBarViewController.selectedIndex = 0
                self.tabBarViewController.tabBar.items![0].badgeValue = "1"
                self.tabBarViewController.selectedViewController?.viewWillAppear(true)
            }
            if pushNotification.type == "vc2"{
                self.tabBarViewController.selectedIndex = 1
            }
            if pushNotification.type == "vc3"{
                self.tabBarViewController.selectedIndex = 2
            }
        }
    }
```

I want then badge value to be incremented on receiving notification if the user is in foreground and background. Thanks in advance

I am updating the badge value in ViewController:

```
    let unreadFeeds = feedsDictionary?.objectForKey("UnReadFeeds") as! NSInteger
      if unreadFeeds > 0 {

      self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].badgeValue = String(unreadFeeds)
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].badgeColor = UIColor(red: 219/255.0, green: 90/255.0, blue: 41/255.0, alpha: 1)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
```

Comment: Please add a little source code to your question.

Comment: now I want to update badge value automatically(increment if there is any existing badge) for IndexPath = 0 when user receives new notification if he is in foreground or background @ventiseis

Answer (score 3):

Whenever user get notification, then you will get callback on Remote notification delegate method. Update the tab bar badge there as below.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].badgeValue = "YourBadgeValue"
```

if your view controller is inside a `navigation controller`, you have to use

```
self.navigationController!.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "YourBadgeValue"
```